# ClearInterval doesn't work. What is the problem? How can I solve it?

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

https://codepen.io/fodi91/pen/ExNqGpY

First I click the random background every 4 seconds button, then I click the random background onclick button, but the interval doesn't stop. Why? How can I solve this?

```
let onClick = document.getElementById('generate');
onClick.addEventListener('click', generator);



let onClick2 = document.getElementById('generate2');
onClick2.addEventListener('click', generator2);

function generator2() {
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

    let background = document.getElementById('random');
    background.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
    myInterval = setInterval(generator2, 2000);
}

function generator() {

    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

    let background = document.getElementById('random');
    background.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    
}
```

Comment: You define `myInterval` where?

Comment: `myInterval = setInterval(generator2, 2000);` will schedule the whole function to be executed again, which includes scheduling a whole new interval every time it runs. You only record a handle to the *last* interval at `myInterval`, so you cannot cancel all the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

Firstly, you need to declare your myInterval variable outside of the `generator2()` function.

The second issue is that your interval function is calling itself creating a recursive loop. Separate your callback which sets the interval from the code you want to execute on each interval.

```
let myInterval;
let onClick = document.getElementById('generate');
. . .

onClick2.addEventListener('click', secondClickHandler);

function secondClickHandler() {
    myInterval = setInterval(generator2, 2000);
}

function generator2() {
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

    let background = document.getElementById('random');
    background.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
}
```

With that in mind, here's how I'd approach it:

```
const generate1Button = document.getElementById('generate');
const generate2Button = document.getElementById('generate2');
const randomBackground = document.getElementById('random');

let backgroundInterval;

generate1Button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clearInterval(backgroundInterval);
    setRandomBackgroundColor();
})

generate2Button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    setRandomBackgroundColor();
    backgroundInterval = setInterval(setRandomBackgroundColor, 2000);
})

function setRandomBackgroundColor() {
    const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

    randomBackground.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two problems:

1. You're using myInterval like it's a global variable, but it's not defined anywhere outside the functions
2. You're calling generator2 recursively, generator2 sets the color, then sets an interval to call generator2, regardless if there's another interval, so with every interval passing you actually set another interval, you'll eventually hang the tab with this. not to mention, myInterval will have a different interval ID, meaning even if you stop it, you only stopped the last running interval. a possible solution is setting the color changing to a different function, and have it called in the interval instead of on click.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the fact that you are defining multiple intervals by calling the generator2 function in the interval itself. So instead, you should use a `setTimeout`. This would cause every `timeout` defined to get cleared (almost) as soon as the timer runs out.

So, the generator functions would change to:

```js
function generator2() {
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

    let background = document.getElementById('random');
    background.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
    myTimeout = setTimeout(generator2, 2000);
}

function generator() {

    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

    let background = document.getElementById('random');
    background.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
}
```

In addition, you would have to ensure the `myTimeout` is declared such that it is accessible by the `generator` function as well, since you wish to clear it on the button click.